# Convert custom Convolution from PyTorch to Tensorflow (2.2.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am currently attempting to convert a custom convolution from PyTorch to Tensorflow (V. 2.2.0).

The convolution is defined in PyTorch as:

```
    self.quantizer = q = nn.Conv1d(1, 2*nq, kernel_size=1, bias=True)
    a = (nq-1) / gap
    #1st half = lines passing to (min+x,1) and (min+x+1/a,0) with x = {nq-1..0}*gap/(nq-1)
    q.weight.data[:nq] = -a
    q.bias.data[:nq] = torch.from_numpy(a*min + np.arange(nq, 0, -1)) # b = 1 + a*(min+x)
    #2nd half = lines passing to (min+x,1) and (min+x-1/a,0) with x = {nq-1..0}*gap/(nq-1)
    q.weight.data[nq:] = a
    q.bias.data[nq:] = torch.from_numpy(np.arange(2-nq, 2, 1) - a*min) # b = 1 - a*(min+x)
    # first and last one are special: just horizontal straight line
    q.weight.data[0] = q.weight.data[-1] = 0
    q.bias.data[0] = q.bias.data[-1] = 1
```

where `nq = 20`, `min = 0` and `max = 1`.

My reimplementation looks like this:

```
my_weight = my_init_weight((1,1,nq*2))
q = tf.nn.convolution(input_q, my_weight)
q = tf.nn.bias_add(q, my_init_bias((40,1), tf.float32))
```

with these these functions as weight and bias initialization:

```
def my_init_weight(shape, dtype=None):

    weights = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.float32)
    weights[:, :, :nq] = -a
    weights[:, :, nq:] = a
    weights[:, :, 0] = weights[:, :, -1] = 0
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(weights, dtype=tf.float32)
def my_init_bias(shape, dtype=None):
    weights = np.zeros(shape[0], dtype=np.float32)
    weights[:nq] = a*min + np.arange(nq, 0, -1)
    weights[nq:] = np.arange(2-nq, 2, 1) - a*min
    weights[0] = weights[-1] = 1
    return weights
```

The input is a matrix with shape `1681, 1, 1600` for PyTorch (as it uses channels first) and `1681, 1600, 1` for Tensorflow (as it uses channels last) and the out put is `1681, 40, 1600` or `1681, 1600, 40`. So it should be correct, however, the output of both convolutions is different.

Input, Output: Tensorflow on a random `100, 100` image:

```
my_weight = my_init_weight((1,1,nq*2))
my_weight = tf.nn.bias_add(my_weight, my_init_bias((40,1), tf.float32))
q = tf.nn.convolution(test_conv, my_weight)

q_left, q_right = tf.split(q, 2, axis=2)
q = tf.math.minimum(q_left, q_right)
nbs = tf.reduce_sum(q, axis=0)
```

[image: Tensorflow]

Input, Output: PyTorch on a random `100, 100` image:

```
output = q(input_t_t)
output = torch.min(output[:,:nq], output[:,nq:]).clamp(min=0)    
nbs = output.sum(dim=-1)
```

[image: PyTorch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution:

I forgot to add the `.clamp(min=0)`.

Adding `q = tf.clip_by_value(q, 0, tf.keras.backend.max(q))` to

```
my_weight = my_init_weight((1,1,nq*2))
my_weight = tf.nn.bias_add(my_weight, my_init_bias((40,1), tf.float32))
q = tf.nn.convolution(test_conv, my_weight)

q_left, q_right = tf.split(q, 2, axis=2)
q = tf.math.minimum(q_left, q_right)
q = tf.clip_by_value(q, 0, tf.keras.backend.max(q)) <-----------
nbs = tf.reduce_sum(q, axis=0)
```

fixed the problem.